# ModuleNotFound seaborn in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, seaborn, spyder

I'm trying to use the seaborn module in the Spyder IDE. I've installed seaborn (and sklearn) through pip install (pip install seaborn, pip3 install seaborn, pip -m install seaborn, conda install seaborn). I've also tried uninstalling it and installing it again. I see it in my pip list. But when I go into Spyder and actually try to import it using "import seaborn as sns", it says "mo module named 'seaborn'".

I've installed other modules (pandas, numpy, etc), so I'm pretty sure my PATH is set appropriately. I found another thread but it was all about starting virtual environments to work with seaborn, which I'd rather not do.

Any ideas? Please keep in mind that I'm fairly a newbie, so I have a basic IDE setup.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check whether the Spyder you are using is the correct one.
You can check this with `which spyder` from the commandline.
It should report Spyder being in the same directory as `pip` and `python` are.
Also, check if you can import Seaborn when you are in a normal Python terminal.
This will help tracking down what part of this operation is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder also has a console of its own. Try `pip install seaborn` in that terminal. Hopefully it will solve your problem.